# ionic cli gives me blank screen (white) on safari and on chrome is normal until I reduce the width of the screen on quasar(vue js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, quasar

hello when I freshly install quasar and add ionic plugin I get a problem running it on macOS safari only and when I get vite error it will work fine also no error in the console I use quasar with javascript and added ionic as a boot any help? this is the content of my boot file

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
// import App from 'src/pages/App.vue'
import router from '/src/router';
import { IonicVue } from '@ionic/vue';
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/vue/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/vue/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/vue/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/display.css';



export default boot(async ( { app } ) => {
  app.use(IonicVue).use(router);
})
```

when I check the html style code  and I tick the box of display:none !important the app get displayed again any idea how to fix that ?
[image: when I check the html style code and I tick the box of display:none !important the app get displayed again any idea how to fix that ?]